# How to open outlook mail (.oft) format in outlook template when used in <a href="mail.oft"> in jsp?

Tags: jsp

Eg:

test.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="mail.oft" > click </a>
</body>
</html>
```

This codes opens mail in browser, i want the mail to open in outlook template when used in jsp page ...

Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: How the file is handled relies on the browser configuration and/or client OS.

Comment: when i create a normal html file,its opening in outlook template but when i crate a jsp page , mail is opening as html page .. So how to configure the browser ??

Comment: Possible that the servlet container doesn't serve this file with the right mime type

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: Yes i am using tomcat

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tomcat, you can explicit the mime-type for this file in `<tomcat-root>/conf/web.xml` :

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>oft</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-outlook</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Searching more, I've not found any official documentation about the above configuration as if you can set it in `<application-root>/WEB-INF/web.xml`, you can try a custom Filter :

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "*.oft")
public class MimeTypeFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-outlook");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: should i do anything in jsp file ?? I have kept the mime mapping in web.xml but still i am getting the same ...

Comment: @user2431829 You have restarted/redeployed?

Comment: I made changes in web.xml and then restarted the server